# ¿por qué no me retorna ninguna fila el select en php?

Tags: php, sql-server

Buen día compañeros espero estén bien.
eh estado intentando realizar una consulta en php con sql server. la consulta ya la hice en sql server (estudio) y la consulta es exitosa, pero al momento de realizara en php no me da nada, ni siquiera errores (oh eso creo no me da nada en la consola ni en la pantalla) la conexión ya la realice y todo es correcto, por lo que será que me pueden ayudar? nunca había hecho una consulta tan compleja que no fuera dentro de un manejador de base de datos.

en esta parte tengo el código.

```
        <table class="table table-hover">
                        <!-- aca estan los titulos de las columnas-->
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID Usuario</th>
                                <th>Nombre(s)</th>
                                <th>Correo</th>
                                <th>Rol</th>
                                <th>Alcance</th>
                                <th>Descripcion Alc</th>
                                <th>Descripcion Rol</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <!-- aca se pondra la consulta -->
                            <?
                        $consulta = "SELECT  CE.ID_USUARIO, PL.NOMBRES, PL.CORREO_E,UROL.ID_ROL , CAL.ID_ALCANCE,
                        CROL.DESCRIPCION , CAL.DESCRIPCION 
                        from CE_CAT_USUARIO AS CE, PL_PERSONAL as PL, 
                        CE_CAT_ROL as CROL, CE_USUARIO_ROL UROL, CE_CAT_ALCANCE CAL
                        where CE.ID_PERSONA = PL.ID_PERSONA 
                        AND
                        CE.ID_USUARIO = UROL.ID_USUARIO
                        and
                        UROL.ID_ROL = CROL.ID_ROL
                        and
                        UROL.ID_ALCANCE = CAL.ID_ALCANCE
                        order by CE.ID_USUARIO"; 

                        $val = sqlsrv_query($conn,$consulta); 
                        while($resultado = sqlsrv_fetch_array($val)){
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span><? echo $resultado['CE.ID_USUARIO']?></span></td>
                                <td><span><? echo $resultado['PL.NOMBRES']?></span></td>
                                <td><span><? echo $resultado['PL.CORREO_E']?></span></td>
                                <td><span><? echo $resultado['UROL.ID_ROL']?></span></td>
                                <td><span><? echo $resultado['CAL.ID_ALCANCE']?></span></td>
                                <td><span><? echo $resultado['CROL.DESCRIPCION']?></span></td>
                                <td><span><? echo $resultado['CAL.DESCRIPCION']?></span></td>
                               
                              
                                <?

                        }
                            ?>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

en el navegador se ve así.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y como tal no me arroja ningún error.

¿me pueden ayudar? tal vez estoy haciendo mal la consulta. pero toda ayuda será muy bien recibida. muchas gracias :)

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: si puedieras colocar aqui un ejemplo minimo con datos: http://sqlfiddle.com/ podria ayudarte...

Comment: ahora si estas usando xampp (php+mysql) en lugar de sqlsrv_query deberias de estar usando PDO ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 nunca eh usado esa herramienta que me comentas. pero los datos que quiero obtener son los que pongo en la tabla :c

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 si, el problema es que la base de datos con la que estoy trabajando esta en sql server y no es mia jeje ... php trabaja mejor con mysql... y PDO voy a buscar ese... nada más lo eh usado 1 o 2 veces

Comment: comiensa a utilizarla por que a simple vista te puede decir que no sale nada por que no hay datos...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 pero como ves la estructura de la consulta es correcta así?

Comment: como voy a saber eso si no veo lo que tienes el SQL???

Comment: Intenta mover el cierre del while debajo del </tr> o </tbody>

Comment: La vieja confiable: justo después del `while`, pon un `var_dump($resultado);` Si no arroja nada, es que no entró al ciclo por lo que no está trayendo nada de la base de datos. De lo contrario, observa bien cómo se llaman los nombres de las columnas, posiblemente no vengan con formato `tabla.columna`, si no `columna` a secas. Finalmente [evita](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags) usar los tags cortos de PHP ya que es una directiva que debe estar habilitada en php.ini y al parecer ha sido removida en php 8.0

Comment: @aeportugal sii hice un vardump y si me retorno los datos... tambien a las columnas les puse el nombre correcto y ya me genera las filas. el problema es que no me pone nada en las filas jajaja pero ya por lo menos vi que el query es correcto

Comment: @aeportugal ya se por que no me retornaba ninguna fila... donde ponia los echo de php solo ponía esto <? ?> pero me faltaba el 
<?php echo $resultado['datos'] ?> y ya me imprimió los resultados

Comment: Si, lo puse en el primer comentario. Parece que la etiqueta `<?` fue deshabilitada en PHP 7.4 y eliminada en 8.0. En su defecto podrías usar la versión corta `<?= $var;?>` que aún es válida.